# javascript getting a 404 file not found error on a pdf but the file is there

Tags: javascript, path, coldfusion

I'm using cold fusion and have created a pdf file using `<cfcontent`.  The file is where it should be.  It has 777 permission, so anyone can access it.  When I open it manually from the folder, it is correct. But when I try to open it with javascript, I get a 404 file not found error. HTTP Status 404 - /opt/lucee/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/reports/ABCrep/templab.pdf

I am referencing the entire path.

Here is how I created the file:

```
<cfdocument format = "pdf" 
        filename = "#extreploc#/templab.pdf" 
        overwrite = 'true'
        pageType = 'custom'
        pageHeight = '11'
        pageWidth = '8.5'
        marginBottom = '.49'
        marginTop = '.49'
        marginLeft = '.29' 
        marginRight = '.29'>

    <cfoutput> #thelabel# </cfoutput>
  </cfdocument>
```

The path extreploc is the full path and a cfoutput in the program shows it as:  /opt/lucee/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/reports/ABCrep/templab.pdf.  It was created with an ExpandPath function.  The call to the javascript is

```
<input type    = "button"             
         class   = 'onoffbut repbutton'
         style   = 'height: 75px'  
         id      = "showlab"             
         value   = "show #aux_mtype# for printing" 
         onclick = "labtest('#extreploc#/templab.pdf')">
```

and the function itself is:

```
<script>
  function labtest(x) {
  alert("got to labtest x is " + x);
  window.open(x);
  }
</script>
```

The alert is functioning and gives me the right path.

Can anyone see what the problem is here?

Comment: If you are opening using `folder/mydocument.pdf`, you are probably directing to your application domain and then that path. `example.com/folder/mydocument.pdf`, which possibly isn't where your file is actually located, hence the 404. Plus, if you're accessing the file via pathname and then via javascript, I don't think that's ever possible for security purposes.

Comment: Hi Abana, the path the 404 is complaining about is exactly the path I am asking for, and exactly the path where the file exists.  However, could you explain your comment about the javascript.  It is working fine in other areas of the application.

Comment: I see. So the images are located in the same domain? If that's the case there shouldn't be a problem. The location of the file is exactly `example.com/opt/lucee/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/reports/ABCrep/templab.pdf`? Are you sure this is where the browser is leading you? There could be some hidden url modifications going on in that area of your application, thus, making your ordinary `window.open()` go haywire. Either way, we need more information. Perhaps a look of the error page and your browser address bar

Comment: The error page is quoted in my question.